# Pass Properties or Managed Object ID Between Views - Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

`enter code here`Using Swift and Xcode 6.

> View One.swift = TableView.
>
> View Two.swift = View w/TextFields (and other UI elements) that change according to item chosen in TableView

I have coded to pass the Managed Object ID chosen in the TableView to View Two (as a delegate property). **But is this the best approach**?

```
    //main view class
    var mainAry = [String]() // for TableView
    var objectsAry = [NSManagedObject]()
    var itemObChosen: NSManagedObject? = nil  //protocol property
    
    //loads the table view and objectsAry
    func loadMyItems() {
           objectsAry.removeAll() 
           let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
           let contextOb: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
           let cdFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
           var getData = contextOb.executeFetchRequest(cdFetch, error: nil)!
            
           if(getData.count > 0) {
                for eachItem in getData {
                    var itemItem = eachItem.valueForKey("itemname") as String!
                    if (itemItem != nil) {
                    objectsAry.append(eachItem as NSManagedObject)
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
    
    //within didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
    itemClkdVar = indexPath.row
    itemObChosen = objectsAry[itemClkdVar] //passed to the other view as chosen object

    //fixed to eliminate mainAry
maincell.textLabel?.text = self.objectsAry[indexPath.row].valueForKey("itemname") as? String
```

Comment: Why not just pass the managed object rather than its id

Comment: I tried that and had errors, but now, with Xcode's help down casting, etc. I have it working. I'm unclear about the memory aspects of Core Data. It seems I have to fetch all objects of an entity into a var, then loop through them for a match. W SQL, you don't load it unless you want it.

Comment: No, you can specify query parameters before you execute the fetch request

Comment: Yes. For example - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1

Comment: I will dig into the predicate info. I couldn't immediate find any predicate that might give me a specific object, but it's probably there. Unless there's a method to extract the object clicked (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) this seems to work fine at this point.

Comment: Normally your table view is driven by an array containing all of your managed objects, so you can simply pass the object from the array element (indexPath.row).  In fact, looking at your code this is what you are doing - itemObjChosen is your managed object. I am. It sure why you have mainArt and objectsAry. Once you have objectsAry you can easily get the itemName property at any time

Comment: Got it! Thx a ton. Just had to tweak loading the table cells.